# Choosing specific Access Point in multiple point that uses EAP/PEAP

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wireless-access-point, peap

I'm viewing one hotspot with several points (different MAC Address) and found that one specific MAC have gives better speed than others, however I don't always get connect to that one (there are about 8 of them). How can I connect to that specific hot spot (specific MAC Address)? I'm using Win 8.1 and I have tried using WirelessMon by PassMark and NetSetMan, but it both don't support EAP/PEAP which is used in my case.